# Whitelist Synapse Spark pool Ip Address

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-synapse

I work with multiple external databases from sources outside Azure, but i work with Synapse Analytics, i'm trying to whitelist my Spark Pool ip address inside my external server's network security configuration to allow queries but i'm not sure which ranges to specify. I have found this different ranges:

[Azure IP Ranges and Service Tags – Public Cloud](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=56519) Searching for DataFactory

[Azure SQL Gateway IP addresses](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/connectivity-architecture?view=azuresql#gateway-ip-addresses) Counts for SQL Pool

But there doesn't seem to be a clear answer besides using a virtual machine with an Integration Runtime to use that single machine ip address.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For now Synapse Spark Pools have no specific ip range, so this is not possible, the correct solution would be to privatize the synapse service with a VNET and then use the gateway ip to peer or go outside.